Site icons all cut off/incorrectly cropped in Hot Network Questions list
As you can see from the image below, the site icons in the Hot Network Questions list are all cut off at the top, with some extra content at the bottom. This issue appears to be occurring specifically on Meta.SE. I checked a few other sites, and all of them looked fine.
This screenshot is from Edge 124.0 on Windows 10. No repro on Chrome 124.0.


Check your zoom setting in the browser.

@PeterJames apparently I had zoom set to 90%. Is this expected behavior (icons being "off" when site is zoomed in/out)?

The sites never formally supported zooming.  the icons are based on a so called "image sprite"  CSS trick which uses one single image with all icons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/favicons-sprite16.png (zoom in!) the "correct" image is then shown by a selecting a small key hole at the right position. The height of the image isn't scaled with the key hole, so things get chopped. Another fail case for this image sprite is/was when new sites launched. For 6 to 8 hours all site icons could be off by one ...

FYI, while using Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, I noticed on Jan. 23 of this year that the tops of various site icons were cut off. After a check for duplicates didn't find anything, I wrote and posted Top parts of some site icons are being cut off, e.g., in list of the highest reputation sites, and in the HNQ. However, when I realized that this had occurred because I, like you, had accidentally set the zoom to 90%, I deleted my question.

If Stack Exchange wants to prioritize accessibility as they’ve been doing lately they should prioritize fixing this, one of the most frequently used browser accessibility features. I’m curious why this fails on Stack Exchange when zooming “just works” on almost literally every other website since about ten years ago (or whenever browsers changed it from just zooming text). My current employer’s website also uses sprite sheets and this doesn’t happen. There’s something unusually broken here, and it should definitely be considered a bug, not by-design.
